# Why the sql could not execute the insert query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to execute below code but I keep receiving below error :

> "Could not execute the insert query."

It seem like the insert into Employees isn't working.

I am not sure what is missing.

Below is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $minitial = $_POST['minitial'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($fname == "" || $minitial == "" || $lname == "" || $gender == "" || 
            $phone == "" || $dob == "" || $ssn == "" || $address == "" || 
            $city == "" || $state == "" || $zip == "" || $email == "" || 
            $username == "" || $password == "") {
        echo "All fields should be filled. Either one or many fields are empty.";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<a href='register.php'>Go back</a>";} 
    else {
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO 'Employees'('fname', 'minitial', 'lname', 'gender', 'phone', 'dob', 'ssn', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'email', 'username', 'password') VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
        or die("Could not execute the insert query.");

            echo "Registration successfully";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
        }
```

Comment: Myqli is built for the sole use of binding params, unlike mysql_, so please bind your params before running a query otherwise you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: I would advice u to start using prepared statements and use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for secure passwords

Comment: and where do you actually close the if statement that execute the entire script?

Answer (score 3):

That's cause you are quoting the table name as pointed below. Don't single quote column names else it's treated as string literal rather a actual table/column name

```
INSERT INTO 'Employees'
```

You actually meant to escape it like

```
INSERT INTO `Employees`
```

Re-write your `INSERT` statement to be like

```
"INSERT INTO `Employees`(`fname`, `minitial`, `lname`, `gender`, `phone`, `dob`, `ssn`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))"
```

Comment: It still not working even after I tried this.                                                                                                           mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `Employees`(`fname`, `minitial`, `lname`, `gender`, `phone`, `dob`, `ssn`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
            or die("Could not execute the insert query.");

Comment: @Jackie, what doesn't work? that's not enough ... post the error statement/msg you get. (OR) what happened when you tried?

Comment: I got this message when I ran the code "Could not execute the insert query." it seem that my Insert Into Employees doesn't work and I don't see why that was case.

Comment: @Jackie, last but not least, see edit in answer and try the edited insert statement and see

Comment: I got this an red underlined , echo "Registration successfully";  in my code after I copied and pasted your line of code, It seem like we are heading in the right direction.

Comment: I got a Syntax error unexpected: echo after: ""

Comment: mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `Employees`(`fname`, `minitial`, `lname`, `gender`, `phone`, `dob`, `ssn`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
                
                    or die("Could not execute the insert query.");
            
                echo "Registration successfully";
                echo "<br/>";

Answer (score 0):

**try this query.**

Because you put *Table name* and *field* name in single quote.

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Employees(fname, minitial, lname, gender, phone, dob, ssn, address, city, state, zip, email, username, password) VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
```

Comment: You really should put a note on this answer other than `try this` also, you should warn them that not binding their params can cause trouble, in case someone google and finds this answer.

Comment: I have tried this               mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Employees(fname, minitial, lname, gender, phone, dob, ssn, address, city, state, zip, email, username, password) VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
            or die("Could not execute the insert query.");

Comment: than echo your query. and directly run in the phpmyadmin query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'` into ` or remove `'` in filed list in insert query.

So you query will be

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `Employees`(`fname`, `minitial`, `lname`, `gender`, `phone`, `dob`, `ssn`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
```

Comment: I have tried with ` and without `, and I still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_error()` won't solve your problem, but it will at least tell you where it is. Replace:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO 'Employees'('fname', 'minitial', 'lname', 'gender', 'phone', 'dob', 'ssn', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'email', 'username', 'password') VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
or die("Could not execute the insert query.");
```

with:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO 'Employees'('fname', 'minitial', 'lname', 'gender', 'phone', 'dob', 'ssn', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'email', 'username', 'password') VALUES('$fname', '$minitial', '$lname', '$gender', '$phone', '$dob', '$ssn', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$username', md5('$password'))")
or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: I received:  Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @Jackie That does what is says on the tin. Your table contains a primary key that is contstrained to always be unique. You're trying to write a value to that column when another row in the table already has that value. Do you know what the primary key is in the table?

Comment: Thank you, table Employees primary key is eID, and it also a foreign key for tables Departments and Manges.

Comment: You don't try to set eID at all. My guess is you haven't defined it to be `AUTOINCREMENT`, so it tries to set it to 0 every time. You have two choices: 1) Make it an `AUTOINCREMENT` field; or 2) Set a value each time!

Comment: Thank you Ben, I'm in the process of adding Autoincrement to my tables now.

Comment: @Jackie Did that solve the problem?